# Cocoa Mac: Get NSViewController by String Name?

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa

How do I get a viewController returned by it's string name? Something to the effect of:

```
NSViewController *foo = [ViewControllerByStringName:@"someCustomController"];
```

THanks

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSClassFromString()` will do you want. For example:

```
NSString *className = "MyClass";
id object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

Comment: THANKS! and hehe I just edited the question to make it easier to read but you hit it on the head :) Just slapped it in and tested it :)